# How do I get an object that is within an array to display on the document or console

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I am trying to make a basic stock keeping tool in which a user can input a bar code and receive information about the product attached to that bar code such as the product name and quantity available etc.

To organise my data I have created a array called products and made an object for each product.

My array currently looks like this :

```
 var products = [
 {
  brand:"Healthy Boy",
  product:"Sweet Chilli Sauce",
  size: 300,
  measurement: "ml",
  barcode:"00909274636143",
  quantity:"2"
 },
 {
  brand:"Golden Dragon",
  product:"rice",
  size: 1,
  measurement: "kg",
  barcode:"5623593845",
  quantity:"5"
 },
 {
  brand:"Golden Dragon",
  product:"rice",
  size: 1,
  measurement: "kg",
  barcode:"5623593845",
  quantity:"5"
 }
];
```

I use two functions to search via the inputting of a  bar code to see if the bar code is part of the array. The functions look like this:

```
function isBarcodeValid (barcode){
for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    if(products [i].barcode === barcode){
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}

function displayBarcode (barcode){
if (isBarcodeValid(barcode)){
    console.log("barcode exists");
} else {
    console.log("invalid barcode");
}
}
```

At the moment I am logging to the console whether or not the bar code is present in the array but is there a way that I can display the information related to each bar code contained within the object?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of return boolean, return the object or null instead:

```
function isBarcodeValid (barcode){
  for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
     if(products [i].barcode === barcode){
      return products[i];
     }
  }
  return null;
}

function displayBarcode (barcode){
  var v = isBarcodeValid(barcode);
  if (v){
    console.log(v);
  } else {
    console.log("invalid barcode");
  }
}
```

Comment: Essentially, this. With your flat structure you can even try console.table(v), for nice formatting.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 var products = [
 {
  brand:"Healthy Boy",
  product:"Sweet Chilli Sauce",
  size: 300,
  measurement: "ml",
  barcode:"00909274636143",
  quantity:"2"
 },
 {
  brand:"Golden Dragon",
  product:"rice",
  size: 1,
  measurement: "kg",
  barcode:"5623593845",
  quantity:"5"
 },
 {
  brand:"Golden Dragon",
  product:"rice",
  size: 1,
  measurement: "kg",
  barcode:"5623593845",
  quantity:"5"
 }
];

function findBarcode (barcode){
  for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    const p = products[i]
      if(p.barcode === barcode){
          return p;
      }
  }
}

function displayBarcode (barcode){
  const barCode = findBarcode(barcode)
  const barcodeIsValid = !!barCode
  if (barcodeIsValid){
      console.log(barCode, "barcode exists");
  } else {
      console.log("invalid barcode");
  }
}

displayBarcode('00909274636143') //present
displayBarcode('not-a-barcode') //present
```

you can return the identified product when you're filtering to see if it is present

Answer (score 0):

You can return the product taking advantage of Array methods and ES6 syntax in javascript to perform a find instead a workaround with for and breaking the for loop retuning data in the middle:

```
'use strict';

const products = [{
  brand: 'Healthy Boy',
  product: 'Sweet Chilli Sauce',
  size: 300,
  measurement: 'ml',
  barcode: '00909274636143',
  quantity: '2',
  }, {
    brand: 'Golden Dragon',
    product: 'rice',
    size: 1,
    measurement: 'kg',
    barcode: '5623593845',
    quantity: '5',
 }, {
  brand: 'Golden Dragon',
  product: 'rice',
  size: 1,
  measurement: 'kg',
  barcode: '5623593845',
  quantity: '5',
}];


/**
 * Look for a given barcode and return the product or null if barcode doesn't exist
 * @param {String} barcode
 * @return {Object} product data or null
 * */
function isBarcodeValid (barcode){
  return products.find(p => p.barcode === barcode);
}

function displayBarcode (barcode) {
  const product = isBarcodeValid(barcode);
  if (product){
    console.log(`barcode exists: ${product}`);
  } else {
      console.log('invalid barcode');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Saw it got answered, but just for some spice:

```
const isValid=(barcode)=>{
    let a=products.findIndex(x=>x.barcode===barcode)
    a>-1?(console.log("barcode exists: "), 
        Object.keys(products[a]).forEach(y=>console.log(y, ":",products[a][y]))):
    console.log("invalid barcode");
}
isValid("5623593845");
```

You can simply return the valid Object, rather than log the properties as I did here.

Answer (score 0):

This ends up being quite concise if you are to utilize ES6 (arrow functions/destructuring) and [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
var products = [{ brand:"Healthy Boy", product:"Sweet Chilli Sauce", size: 300, measurement: "ml", barcode:"00909274636143", quantity:"2" }, { brand:"Golden Dragon", product:"rice", size: 1, measurement: "kg", barcode:"5623593845", quantity:"5" }, { brand:"Golden Dragon", product:"rice", size: 1, measurement: "kg", barcode:"5623593845", quantity:"5" } ];

const getBarcode = (bc) => products.find(({barcode}) => barcode == bc)
const displayBarcode = (bc) => console.log(getBarcode(bc) || 'invalid barcode')

displayBarcode(00909274636143)
displayBarcode(009092746111136143)
```

The idea is if you find it you would simply output the object. If not the `||` (or) operator would evaluate the `invalid barcode` string.